# Scraping temperature and humidity rate with cheerio

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I've been trying to scrap the following webpage with **cheerio** in order to get the latest **temperature and humidity** rate for a little project of mine:
[Website link](http://www.meteociel.fr/temps-reel/obs_villes.php?code2=7630)

Unfortunately, it seems like I've got to dig through a lot of tags and I can't find my way around. I've tried to inspect the element to see its css path but it did no good.
The code I've tried is the following (it's based on the css selector I get when I inspect the element):

```
setInterval(function getTempAndHumidity() 
{
    var url = 
    {
        url: "http://www.meteociel.fr/temps-reel/obs_villes.php?code2=7630",
        method: 'GET',
        proxy: webproxy
    };

    request(url, function (error, response, body) 
    {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
        {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);           
            console.log($('tr.texte > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > center:nth-child(18) > table:nth-child(3) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1)').html());
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Error when getting the temperature and humidity rate: " + error);
        }
    })
}, 2000);
```

I just get 'null' so it doesn't seem to work.

It would be a huge help if someone could give me a hand on this matter!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the edit Sid. I'll keep this in mind for my next post!

Comment: You are welocme @FlyinPoulpus and please post your code in place of link which will be better to help you

Comment: The link was just the website I'm trying to scrap actually. But I added a some code!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way around my issue. But it's VERY ugly. I'd like to find a more elegant way to do this!

```
$ = cheerio.load(body);
var content = $('h1').parent().nextAll().nextAll().next().text();
var catch_values = content.match(/.*km\s+(\d+\.\d+).*(\d\d)%.*/);
var temp = catch_values[1];
var humid_rate = catch_values[2];
```

Any help, advice or input is welcome!